# ASP.Net MVC Ajax call in View to Controller not Working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view, that when loaded, it should send a request back to the controller to change do an async task.

The AJAX call in the view:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                 url: '@Url.Action("GetWifis", "RobotSsh")',
                 type: 'POST',
                 success: function () {
                     console.clear();
                     console.log("success");
                 },
            });
        });
    </script>   
}
```

The method in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetWifis(RobotSshModel model)
    {
        await model.GetAllWifiSsids();
        model.RobotPassword = "test";
        
        // Render the page again, keeping the data user has entered by supplying the model.
        return View("~/Views/Home/RobotSsh.cshtml", model);
    }
```

The "success" string is actually logged to the console, even if the GetWifis function is not called.

I have tried to change to GET request, partial views, other stuff, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

The `IActionResult` appears to be sending back a view that contains HTML.

The ajax call is working fine but when `success` is called the function does not know what to do with HTML page, it just ignores it.

The quick answer to your problem is to change

```
success: function () {
    self.location = '/home/index';
},
```

But also you are posting on `$(document.ready)` which will result in a infinite loop!

Therefore you need to consider what you are trying to do.

Either the `GetWifis` method needs to return a partial view with the data in and you replace your DOM DIV with the partial HTML

**OR**

your `GetWifis` method returns some JSON that you use to update the DOM.

Comment: This results in an infinite reload loop

Comment: Ah yes that is because you are submittng data on page ready instead of a button click. TBH your whole thought process needs a little help :)

Comment: I have a simple web page that has two dropdowns, what I do is that I scan nearby wifis and then want to show them in the two dropdowns. The problem is I can't execute an async task in the model before the page loads (i.e. the constructor). I can set static initial values in the dropdowns before the page loads, but that's not what I need. So what I am trying to do now is to load the page, when loading is finished, call the async wifi scanner function, and then return a new view with the dropdowns populated.

Comment: In that case your `IActionResult` needs to return a json payload that you then use to populate the dropdowns using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be sending a POST request to the controller when the page loads. This is not how POST should be used. Instead, you need to use GET (both in your AJAX request and as an attribute on your controller endpoint).

I would then ditch using @Url.Action() in the AJAX call and would also change the controller endpoint to return a JSON object instead of a view.